# Interface Builder vs Cocos 2D - how choice the best for your app

Tags: iphone, performance, cocos2d-iphone

I was a flash developer for 3 years, and in the last 5 months, i begin the iphone development, i do 2 applications with interface builder for clients, and now i really want to do a little game, is quite simple, one match 3! I made the engine in interface builder, and seens good to me! But after i read some posts, i really want to try it in the cocos2D! So, in 2 days i rewrite all my first engine for cocos2D, very annoying upsidedown coordinates but ok, i really do! But the performance side by side with interface builder version is really scare! Many Many slow downs at the cocos2d side! And the animation seens bugged to me! I really scare! I really don't know what is the best choice for a simple game.
And i want some opinions:

Using cocos2d when need some physics? When we have many objects at screen? What is the performance boost i have with cocos2D?

I have how to share this 2 applications with you guys?! Without your UID?!

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Interface Builder is a development tool for laying out interfaces, and Cocos2D is a very broad 2-D game programming framework.  What do they have to do with each other?  Why are you asking about distribution?

Comment: So, sorry about that! What i calling Interface Builder, its a build without any other frameworks, just iphone sdk base. clearly now? Or i calling wrong again? What is this name cocoa?

Comment: "What is this name cocoa?"

Wow. I think you should go ahead and read a lot of Cocoa literature before you try to develop an iPhone app for a client. I have found that the extra time it takes to read lots of documentation in order to really understand a topic is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d uses chipmunk, which IMHO is a great physics library if all you need is 2d!  Apple doesn't support ad-hoc distribution without knowing the Device ID of the test device!

Comment: Humm, so the physics is the reason to use cocos2d? Right?!

Comment: you can use Chipmunk by itself without having to use all of cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

I think baDa is asking when to use cocos2D and Interface Builder. Since you can develop games using Interface Builder, is it advisable to do so? What are the performance differences between this two approach (cocos2d vs Interface Builder)?

I also had a confusion and ask this to my self when i was just starting to program. After working with several games. I reallized that you can actually combine this two approaches. The big BUT is, when working with objects dynamically (specially with bunch of images) using IB, it totally removes the flexibility of the code. Adding/removing images, adjusting coordinates and replaceing scenes is just too awkward, bulky, and wastefull to implement.

My simpole rule is to use coocs2d for game developemnt and IB for other apps that is reach in interfaces.